# How to display search results in a new form

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

I've created a system and within that system i've a find/search page and a find/search results page. Basically, the find/search page consists of a number of text fields and the more the user completes, the more efficient the search will be. 
I'm using SQL server 2005 to store the data and I can easily update/insert/save new data but I don't know how to search for the data ...
I want the user to fill out the fields in the find/search form and for the results to appear in the find/search results page. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of Data you need to search.

If it's generic text data the best way is to use [Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142545%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Ive a customer form that contains 3 different sections under it (customer details, acc info, business info). The user can go to the find/search form and will be presented with a number of options to help search for the record. So once they enter in the details and press the find/search button, the information from the database should be retrieved and displayed in the find/search results page. Would I be best to create a SQL statement?

Comment: If customer details, acc info and business info are all text, the best way is to create a SQL statement. Look for Full-Text search and VB.net there should be a lot of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are a number of ways you could achieve this. One possible way would be to pass the search criteria to the search results page via query string. Another way which is very similar is to store the search criteria in a session and redirect to the search results page. In either case on the search results page you'd want to take the data and build your SQL query. Depending on what you need you could utilize a full-text search like Kesty has suggested or you could simply use FIELD like '%user entered data%' in your queries. It really depends on your needs.

Comment: That's great! Thank you both so much for your help. Going to give it a go now and hopefully it works!